# parentNode.rowIndex not working in chrome

Tags: javascript

I am adding listeners to the cells of the table so that i can get the cell index when a particular cell is clicked. However i am unable to get the value of row index in chrome. This works fine in IE10 and Firefox. The code is:

```
function AttachEvents() {
    var cls = document.getElementById("TableContents").getElementsByTagName("td");

    for ( var i = 0; i < cls.length; i++ ) {
        if ( cls[i].addEventListener ) {
            cls[i].addEventListener("click", alertRowCell, false);
        } else if ( cls[i].attachEvent ) {
            cls[i].attachEvent("onclick", alertRowCell);
        }
    }
}

function alertRowCell(e) {
    var cell = e.target || window.event.srcElement;
    //alert( cell.cellIndex + ' : ' + cell.parentNode.rowIndex );
    if (cell.cellIndex == 1) {
        alert(" The row index is " + cell.parentNode.rowIndex);
        highlight();
    }
}
```

How this can be resolved in Chrome?

Comment: Error? What element is `cell.parentNode` in Chrome?

Comment: Could you please explain how it fails to work so we aren't forced to find out ourselves?

Comment: Except in chrome, the cell.parentNode.Rowindex returns the actual row clicked. In chrome it returns -1

Comment: alex, cell is a HTMLTablecellElement

Comment: [I cannot reproduce it](http://jsbin.com/AwAgUW/1/edit?html,js,output) :-?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily refer to the clicked element with `this`.

In *your* case:

```
function alertRowCell(evt) {
    var tr = this.parentNode;
    // do something with tr...
}
```

The reason I'm saying it is because if your table structure is...

```
<tr>
    <td><span>Hello</span></td>
</tr>
```

... then `e.target` is `span` whose `parentNode` is `td` and not `tr`.

Try this example: **http://jsfiddle.net/naJBq/**